# wp_list_categories change the html output format?

Tags: php, wordpress

When you enable show_count in wp_list_categories function, the default output looks as follows:

```
  <li><a href="http://example.com/category/foo/">Foo</a> (559)</li>
```

where (559) is the total post count for the category Foo. I want the output in the following format

```
  <li><a href="http://example.com/category/foo/">Foo (559)</a></li>
```

So I wrote the following php code

```
  <?php $cat_list = wp_list_categories('sort_column=name&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=0&depth=4&show_count=1&exclude=some_value'); 
                  $cat_list = str_replace('</a>','',$cat_list);
                  $cat_list = str_replace(')', ') </a>', $cat_list);
                  echo $cat_list;
                  ?>
```

However, the output does not change. I get the same output. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `&echo=0` with your parameters

try like this

```
$cat_list = wp_list_categories('sort_column=name&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=0&depth=4&show_count=1&echo=0'); 
$cat_list = preg_replace('/<\/a> \(([0-9]+)\)/', ' (\\1)</a>', $cat_list);
echo $cat_list;
```